# Qt: Capture image without saving - QCameraImageCapture

Tags: c++, qt

I was torn between using OpenCV and QCamera for a project I'm working on.

Basically I want a user to input how many frames they want to capture, the camera will then take that amount of images applying a Gaussian filter I have written with both a CUDA and CPU implementation.

Data is then returned and put into a graph so I can analyse the performance difference.

I have set most of my application up, but I'm struggling at the final hurdle, I have created a `QCameraViewFinder`, `QCameraImageCapture` and `QCamera` object.  In my while loop I am then calling the following code:

```
do
    {
       imageCapture->capture();

       //cpu method call here

       // Emit the frame number from the thread back to GUI for update
       emit frameProcessed(QString::number(currFrame));

       currFrame++;
       frames--;
} while(frames > 0);
```

How would I extract the image created by `imageCapture->capture` without saving it to my machine?  The only data I am concerned with is the time in ms that the functions take to compute, so saving the raw image data is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure that the buffer destination is supported:

   ```
   imageCapture.
     isCaptureDestinationSupported(QCameraImageCapture::CaptureToBuffer)
   ```
2. If so, set the buffer destination, and buffer format and resolution, etc.
3. Finally, receive the captured frames in a slot connected to the `imageAvailable(int, const QVideoFrame &)` signal.