# Capture image without saving

Tags: android, c++, qml

Based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431119/qt-capture-image-without-saving-qcameraimagecapture), is there a way to process an image from camera in QML without saving it?

Starting from the example of the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameracapture.html#capture-method) the capture() function save the image to Pictures location. 
What I would like to achieve, is to process the camera image every second using onImageCaptured but I don't want to save it to the drive.

I've tried to implement a cleanup operation using onImageSaved signal but it's affecting onImageCaptured too .

Comment: It really depends on what you want to to. If you just want to process frames (e.g. search for tags/Qr codes) you can hook up the [mediaObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#mediaObject-prop) and that's it. If you want to  do real-time filtering and overlay, then more work is needed. See the link at the beginning of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33238150/2538363) for more details about second scenario.

Comment: What I would like to achieve is scan a QR code. Since I cannot use grabWindow() because of [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53083) I would like to capture the camera output every second and process the image.

Comment: So based on your suggestion of using mediaObject, once I get a reference to QCamera object, what I need to do then?

Comment: I've added an answer. I can't post the full code but I hope I've given you the right tools to build the complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33238150/2538363) you can bridge C++ and QML via the [`mediaObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#mediaObject-prop). That can be done via `objectName` (as in the linked answer) or by using a dedicated `Q_PROPERTY` (more on that later). In either case you should end up with a code like this:

```
QObject * source  // QML camera pointer obtained as described above
QObject * cameraRef = qvariant_cast<QMediaObject*>(source->property("mediaObject"));
```

Once you got the hook to the camera, use it as a source for a [`QVideoProbe`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoprobe.html#details) object, i.e.

```
QVideoProbe *probe = new QVideoProbe;
probe->setSource(cameraRef);
```

Connect the `videoFrameProbed` signal to an appropriate slot, i.e.

```
connect(probe, SIGNAL(videoFrameProbed(QVideoFrame)), this, SLOT(processFrame(QVideoFrame)));
```

and that's it: you can now process your frames inside the `processFrame` function. An implementation of such a function looks like this:

```
void YourClass::processFrame(QVideoFrame frame)
{
    QVideoFrame cFrame(frame);
    cFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);
    int w {cFrame.width()};
    int h {cFrame.height()};
    QImage::Format f;
    if((f = QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cFrame.pixelFormat())) == QImage::Format_Invalid)
    {
        QImage image(cFrame.size(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        // NV21toARGB32 convertion!!
        //
        // DECODING HAPPENS HERE on "image"
    }
    else
    {
        QImage image(cFrame.bits(), w, h, f);
        //
        // DECODING HAPPENS HERE on "image"
    }
    cFrame.unmap();
}
```

Two important implementation details here:

1. Android devices use [YUV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.E2.80.B2UV420sp_.28NV21.29_to_RGB_conversion_.28Android.29) which is not supported currently by `QImage` and which should be converted by hand. I've made the strong assumption here that all the invalid formats are YUV. That would be better managed via `ifdef`'s conditionals over the current OS.
2. The decoding can be quite costy so you can skip frames (simply add a counter to this method) or off load the work to a dedicated thread. That also depend on the pace at which frames are elaborated. Also reducing their size, e.g. taking only a portion of the `QImage` can greatly improve performances.

---

For that matter I would avoid at all the `objectName` approach for fetching the `mediaObject` and instead I would [register a new type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html) so that the `Q_PROPERTY` approach can be used. I'm thinking about something along the line of this:

```
class FrameAnalyzer 
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QObject* source READ source WRITE setSource)
    QObject *m_source;  // added for the sake of READ function 
    QVideoProbe probe;
    // ...

public slots:
    void processFrame(QVideoFrame frame);
}
```

where the `setSource` is simply:

```
bool FrameAnalyzer::setSource(QObject *source)
{
    m_source = source; 
    return probe.setSource(qvariant_cast<QMediaObject*>(source->property("mediaObject")));
}
```

Once registered as usual, i.e.

```
qmlRegisterType<FrameAnalyzer>("FrameAnalyzer", 1, 0, "FrameAnalyzer");
```

you can directly set the `source` property in QML as follows:

```
// other imports
import FrameAnalyzer 1.0

Item {
    Camera {
        id: camera

        // camera stuff here

        Component.onCompleted: analyzer.source = camera
    }

    FrameAnalyzer {
        id: analyzer
    }
}
```

A great advantage of this approach is readibility and the better coupling between the `Camera` code and the processing code. That comes at the expense of a (slightly) higher implementation effort.